# World Map Zoom with D3 + ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I found following code for zoom in a simple D3 solution which works well with Javascript:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
        .on("zoom", function() {
            projection.translate(d3.event.translate).scale(d3.event.scale);
            feature.attr("d", path);
            circle.attr("transform", ctr);
        })
        ;

zoom.translate(projection.translate())
            .scale(projection.scale())
            .scaleExtent([h / 6, h])
        ;
```

When I try to convert this code in D3 + ReactJS, I get issues. There have been many since I've tried so many different solutions. The latest one zooms my world map once but it's all a mess.

This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'd3';
import * as d3Z from 'd3-zoom'
import * as d3 from 'd3-selection';
//import d3Scale from 'd3-scale'
import { geoMercator, geoPath } from 'd3-geo';
import './WorldMap.css';
import countries from '../resources/world-countries.json';

//
export default class WorldMap extends Component {

  componentDidUpdate() {

    const width = 1300, //document.body.clientWidth,
      height = 600;//document.body.clientHeight;
    const circleRadius = 2;
    const lstRadius = [7, circleRadius];
    const lstColor = ["green", "white"];
    const duration = 500;
    const lstShots = [];
    const projection = geoMercator();
    const path = geoPath()
      .projection(projection);

    const d3Zoom = d3Z.zoom();


    for (var i = 0; i < this.props.data.length; i++) {

        lstShots.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.props.data[i])));
    }

    const getCirclePos = (d) => {
      return "translate(" + projection([d.long, d.lat]) + ")";
    }

    const svgObj = d3.select(this.refs.svgMap);

    const feature = svgObj
      .selectAll("path.feature")
      .data(countries.features)
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "feature");

    projection
      .scale(width / 6.5)
      .translate([width / 2, height / 1.6]);

    const zoom = d3Zoom
                  .on("zoom", function() {

                    console.log(d3.event);
                      projection.translate([d3.event.transform.x, d3.event.transform.y]).scale(d3.event.scale);
                      feature.attr("d", path);
                    //  circle.attr("transform", getCirclePos);
                  })
                  ;

    svgObj.call(zoom);

// console.log(zoom);

    // zoom.translateTo(projection.translate())
    //           .scale(projection.scale())
    //           .scaleExtent([height / 6, height])
    //       ;

    feature.attr("d", path);
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    const circle = svgObj.selectAll("circle")
      .data(lstShots)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("r", circleRadius)
      .attr("fill", 'white')
      .attr("transform", getCirclePos)
      .attr("node", function(d) { return JSON.stringify(d); })
      .style("cursor", "pointer");


  }

  render() {
    return (

      <svg ref="svgMap"></svg>
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is that `d3.event` does not contain fields of `translate` or `scale` which I have seen people use in other example of `d3-zoom`. While I have replaced `translate` with `transform` in zoom function, I don't know what to replace `d3.event.scale` with.

Comment: which version of d3 is used in the example and which version of d3 do you use?

Comment: d3 v4 sir........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you port code from d3v3 to d3v4 you need to do it all, `d3.event.scale` does not exist in d3v4

```
projection.translate([d3.event.transform.x, d3.event.transform.y]).scale(d3.event.transform.k);
```

You need to initialise the zoom too

```
svgObj.call(zoom);
svgObj.call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.translate(projection.translate()[0], projection.translate()[1]).scale(projection.scale()));
```

Don't use ref strings but [Callback Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

I needed to use `componentDidMount()` to see anything.

Comment: I did try `scale(d3.event.transform.k)` yesterday but it wasn't working. The real problem turned out to be the fact that component updates periodically and my code is written in `componentDidUpdate`. So zoom only worked until the component was updated.